Expansion of the universe and its effects upon causal determination and freedom of choice
TL;DR: Does the continuous expansion of the observable universe quite literally create more directions from which totally unpredictable surprise influences can come? I think the answer is "Yes!"
Context
The aspect of this that interests me at the moment is how it bears on the often badly conflated question of the reality of choices we can make versus a purported total determination of all the actions and reactions we can manifest in a given situation. My understanding of our situation is naturalistic, ie I deny "supernatural" influences and/or entities (I am an ex-Xian and I do understand those kind of issues, thank you). Therefore we don't have to talk about "free will" as if it is some kind of thing-in-itself, nor do we need to consider ideas of predestination; I think modern physics has (fairly clearly) eliminated both of these, particularly the latter. This is because modern physics has eliminated the kind of billiard-ball-bouncing certainty of causation that many people previously believed in, up until the early twentieth century. As I see it, what we now have instead is an ever deepening understanding of structures and how in living things these are usually dynamic and can manifest as cyclical processes; and we have an ever deepening understanding of information and how it is embodied in living things.
As far as I can see the world of living things is probablistically determined and so is the human cultural world. We therefore live our lives on the basis of expectations which we have been learning since the day we were born. We have evoIved to be constantly looking and planning ahead - usually automatically and unconsciously - and assessing how the actual situation differs from expectations in relation to most of what is occurring around us - once again automatically and unconsciously. (Our rememberable awareness, also called consciousness, can be seen as us recognising and dealing with significant discrepancies between prediction and actuallity.)
Most speakers of English are well familiar with the term "Murphy's Law" which is most often summarised as: "If something can go wrong, it will!" This apparently is not actually what the eponymous Murphy originally said, but then his 'Law' had its way of course. I think it is reasonable to consider that Murphy's Law as such is part of our common or garden experience of entropy, and that this is ultimately the result of the expansion of the universe. A different way of putting it is: in any given situation there is almost always more which can happen then we want to happen, and usually more can happen than we can possibly know about.
That is because in an expanding universe there is always going to be an excess of ways that things can be arranged compared to what we have planned for. I am sure this glosses over too much for some people but the above is basically correct and it is about energy and influences moving 'outwards', so to speak. In our case this refers mostly to energy coming to Earth from the Sun, passing through living sytems here, then ultimately escaping to the heat sink of dark night. There are however sources of potentially very powerful energy, that can impinge on Earth, scattered throughout the universe. This energy can take the form of high-end gamma rays, or ions travelling at almost the speed of light.
So what?
My question concerns the fact that the amount of distant universe which can potentially affect things here on Earth has always been increasing. What I mean is, currently, the "observable universe" which is the amount of light and/or other energy that has been travelling away from its sources for long enough to be able to reach us is expanding at something like the speed of light.  We can say therefore that the region of space-tiem containing   potential outside sources of influences is expanding at something near the speed of light but of course most of that new volume of "observable" space is vacuum and as such is not likely to be the original source of whatever kind of particle it is. But then again something could have been "just passing through" that particular void. As I see it this amounts to an ever increasing number of directions that extraneous influences could potentially come from. Furthermore it is logical to assume this has always been the case up until now.
Some time in the distant future however this will cease to be the case because, due to the expansion of the universe itself, the sources capable of emitting light which can reach us will have moved too far away.
(NB, There are several informative videos on YouTube which explain that last issue.)
Whether or not this makes a significant difference to the general situation of entropy on Earth being a local manifestation of the expansion of the universe per se is a question for mathematicians, which I am not.
It just occurred to me the other day as being yet another reason for firmly rejecting arguments against freedom of choice based upon rigidly mechanistic ideas of determinism. All of the more compex animals on Earth have evolved relevant methods for testing their environment and, generally speaking, the bigger the brain the greater the capacity to make assesssments based on both in-built and learned criteria.
For us humans with proportionately the biggest brains on the planet, instinctive criteria, based upon fundamental discriminations between life-threatening potential versus life-enhancing potential, are expressed as emotional charge attached to perceptions and memories. We weigh things up, either quickly or slowly, based on our experience so far and then act accordingly. Most of this happens unconsciously because we have already learned so much about our world and we have adapted to it, but this does not stop our actions being behaviours which we originate.
The extent to which we decide appropriately will always be a question of fact in each case and, in principle at least, is not certainly predictable by anybody because nobody can know the future. What we can strive for is to be a person who makes the best decisions he, she. or they, know how to. Accepting responsibility for our own actions is a prerequisite for attaining greater freedom in the form of becoming more truly what we have the potential to be.

I do not quite follow how what we can possibly know and plan for affects what can determine events, with or without our knowing. Determinism and predictability (especially, by us) are two different things. And why is expansion of the universe particularly relevant? It is not like it is expanding into an ambient space and interacting with ever new parts of it. It is more like the surface of an inflating balloon, the same old surface, only stretched. What goes on there may or may not be determined, but what does the expansion matter?

@MarkPeaty Expansion of the universe means an increase of the distance between each pair of galaxies. Which conclusions do you draw from this fact and why?

You could read about Unchalla in the book "Radix" by A. A. Atanasio.

@Conifold I was mainly concerned to add further leverage against the 19th century concept/misconception of determinism as something capable of supporting absolute certainty on the part of some hypothetical G/god/s or the like. I see now that I should have said "observable universe" in the TL;DR and likewise in the discussion. So I will edit my post to clarify this..

@JoWehler See also  my response to Conifold.
"Increase of distance between each (far away) pair of galaxies" ensures there is a heat sink of dark night out there. We can exist because of this, ie there is entropy everywhere and evolution of complexity based on cyclical self replication where a sufficiently stable context endures for long enough. The way I see it, what we call entropy (LOL, incl. Murpy,s Law,) is the expansion of the universe "writ small".

"For us humans with proportionately the biggest brains on the planet" Humans do not actually have the largest brains in proportion to their bodies. Apparently, that honor belongs to a particular species of ant.  https://www.livescience.com/largest-brain-body-size

@D.Halsey Thank you for that clarification; if I were an overly sensitive fellow I might feel that us 'brainy' humans have had our parade throroughly rained upon! I am consoled  by the thought that those critters are just so small they have hit the minimum number of neurons needed to be successful at being ants! I suspect other of their body parts may be proportionately smaller as a consequence.

This question is a complex one, which you would be better to ask in separate questions.  However, I have done reading in each tier of your question, and think I can answer the whole thing.
As I read your question, you are asking:



is the expansion of the universe effectively decreasing entropy and increasing unpredictability due to the expanding event horizon?




Will this continue to be the case even in a dark cold distant future?




Does this decrease in entropy and predictability refute determinism and therefore enable free will?



For 1) Victor Stenger wrote a very interesting chapter in his book Has Science Found God, in which he notes the peculiar effect that an expanding universe has on entropy.  Entropy continues to increase in an expanding universe, but the maximum potential entropy grows dramatically, which increases the potential for a universe to do work, even with entropy growth. See https://www.amazon.com/Science-Latest-Results-Purpose-Universe/dp/1591020182/ref=mp_s_a_1_3?crid=4D9G1ZBBD2U9&dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.9aRhdkjwNBjXtlbV98Dv-ABQVHsFzVGGVOvNEft9sNEbfuJpaxc9Rc5xAq9a5BPPK9pKBD8_MnoKT6h3frUy-Hgj3fStGuQE4s9OpwGiU5vmgROUjscsECVe1tSDSjT5BWB_d95rpkALDmC-YsZFTN3Ed1LBr_1JeepK3glIUNUwIMlXl-Qq4v0xrTPwuFhe7f8XMeqk_WfP_4ClO3WGLQ.3c5_akHqScMU754foXQUMeNNm22Vy8TA9ElCqcLNdvQ&dib_tag=se&keywords=victor+stenger+books&qid=1715546042&sprefix=victor+stenger+books%2Caps%2C202&sr=8-3. This increase in potential is effectively same phenomenon you noted of more possible interactions over time.  So yes, a growing universe does peculiarly useful things to entropy that could enable life (and agency, which is what you are trying to get to).
For 2) I would recommend a chapter of Freeman Dyson’s book Infinite in All Directions.  https://www.amazon.com/Infinite-All-Directions-Lectures-April-November/dp/0060728892/ref=mp_s_a_1_4?crid=ES9BFKCCKQL0&dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.U9PuLoSNyNOwzwUc8Q1AX2B78_rlTcxwfiWSHN6mkF18ShqP2_O-23gJuBhGRJ2gQwNWlBEEEj1sv5_g9Vkip4gAZLCA62s3OmKGRzOlnUbwhge0upHM4mV0d0bR0Ftb8zgZgOiC5IJ6FkTMIYnU6cILl92poRIvI1VInwTLhHGKXvyAzfIvzAtZ14gLTTnh-J7k-ssP1X1tWifm3Rn2hQ.5tE7FkenLMbxF5WEYR3KWHHer_cxSyITmga3jwBDSDE&dib_tag=se&keywords=freeman+dyson+books&qid=1715547830&sprefix=freeman+dyson+books%2Caps%2C211&sr=8-4  In one chapter, Dyson explores the possibility of life (defined as complex organized entities doing work) existing at very cold late universe conditions.  He postulates at each of three very cold universe states ways that organized work could be done.  Getting to each of them would require life to reconstitute its basic substrate (our wet warm bodies would not be sustainable at any of these times) but given his basic definition of intelligent life, yes it would be possible, and per his projection it would likely be possible forever.
This isn’t exactly the question you asked, but his answer answers your question too.  In an expanding universe yes signaling between distant parts would continue to increase forever.
For 3), the answer however is widely taken as “no”.  While determinism is reasonably taken as refuted by quantum physics, uncertainty by itself, whether amplified by an expanding universe or not, is not sufficient to justify libertarian free will.  Indeterminacy is not willing or freedom.  It is a prerequisite, but does not get one there by itself.
To get to libertarian free will, one must have several things:

Indeterminacy
Within a close to deterministic universe where physical causation is mostly reliable
Agent Causation as an third logic option between determinism and randomness
And some way for agent causation to be realized in the physical world.

We seem to have the first two, and your two preamble questions emphasize that our universe amplifies the potential for indeterminism.  The third is still an open question though.  Agent Causation theorists have been working to come up with a viable logic of agent causation. The best I have seen is from Helen Steward.  https://www.amazon.com/Metaphysics-Freedom-Helen-Steward/dp/0198706464/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?crid=3A24VV7VHTQHP&dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.ZAsWEAyO_fzWl_FASlA2H7cnNhKkzBiielTgY94k6cyJGQ5ZKosPczfI0MF6vaHMA8SwjEFmXFkyamSpuCQHGgWTvHoskCmIMgrhFCHJX-5GaC-kOqHYs3HoQIaAokbZ0Wwra95R0QSIc6FZ5V71GvrT76WFJGH8l6pCa2iHVQzyoX87h-sxGqdyEm-2vPdeCq9oQ45puIynH6Gp1TuzrA.jQb9lkyq-uzuzYEO3Xv8svUkl6OTPaT5LtGG1kIdcSM&dib_tag=se&keywords=an+metaphysics+of+freedom&qid=1715549192&sprefix=an+metaphysics+of+freedom%2Caps%2C203&sr=8-1  I am not convinced she has fully characterized Agent Causation, but she did very useful thinking on the subject.
Given that there are infinite possible logics, Steward’s pretty close model is reasonably taken as improvable to match our conception of agent causation.
The final question is whether we live in a universe where this agent causation is actualized.  This is a question that dualists have to try to answer.  I see you have rejected spiritual dualism, but you may be open to a secular emergent dualism in the mode of Popper’s thinking.  Here is an answer that explains how dualists have proposed this actualization to occur:
https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/112729/29339

Thank you for your thoughtful treatment of my question.
I never before heard of the increase of maximum potential entropy in an ever expanding universe causing an increase of the the potential to do work! A provocatve thought!
I thought only an increase of entropy can occur for the universe as a whole; And this because the U is expanding.
Thanks also for the ref to Helen Stewart. I don't have access to that book but I am currently viewing a video interview with her on YT and I like the way she thinks. My thoughts seem to be similar to hers   More later....

Wikipedia has great articles on various definitions of event horizons  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon and the observable universe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe
Based on those articles, the common mainstream science view is not that the observable universe will keep growing in the sense of continuously including new sources of information, but rather that it will shrink in the sense that we'll get news slower and slower over time from faraway objects such they appear to practically freeze (even if in terms of size, it will keep growing).
Let me quote:

As the universe's expansion is accelerating, all currently observable objects, outside the local supercluster, will eventually appear to freeze in time

As such the core assumption of the questions seems to be in conflict with current cosmology.
If the universe were not expanding faster forever, then the observable universe would keep growing in terms of including new information, so even though this seems to contradict current cosmology, we can ponder such a situation as a mere though experiment.
When an observer in a fully observable, fully deterministic system that has laws making it also fully predictable, then an ever growing observable universe would indeed prevent such an observer from predicting the future based on their knowledge, because future states would become influenced by information that was not observable at earlier times due to the limits of the observable universe.
So in a way yes, an observable universe growing in that sense would make it (further) impossible to predict the future perfectly.
However this would not necessarily make the universe itself non-deterministic or non-predictable from the outside, an outside observer not bound by the limits of the observable universe might still be able to fully predict future states in such a situation.
The rest of the question relating to free will and evolution is a strained argument and the various aspects of it have already better existing questions and answers on this site. In short, determinism does not imply predictability, lack of predictability does not imply lack of determinism, free will does not depend on predictability, some free will definitions are compatible with determinism. So even if the cosmology in the question were not wrong, several other philosophic assumptions in the questions are also wrong or lack explicit statement of what the OP believes to be true.
